# I need help installing a canon mp620 printer

Tags: printing, canon

I am having problems installing my canon mp620 wireless printer.  The system sees the printer but when I try to print a test page it only adds to the print cue without completing the task.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Canon MP620 (on Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04) and fixed it by following the advice [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+question/179934).

One of the posts suggests using BJNP, a protocol used by Canon printers. Following this advice, I tried adding the printer using the device URI: "bjnp://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8611", where 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx' is the printer IP address.

You may have to make an exception for the relevant port in UFW to get the scanner to work, in this case:

```
sudo ufw allow 8611
```

After that I found both printing and scanning work flawlessly.

Hope that helps.